# When sending money through Paypal which details does the receiver see?

Tags: paypal, privacy

When sending money through PayPal which details of the payer, the receiver gets? and what's the way to minimize it for the minimum details?

Answer (score 1):

Paypal shows your full name, email, amount sent, and any note you add. They also get a Paypal generated Transaction ID.

I'm not sure what you mean by "minimizing it for the minimum."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added one word that was omitted from the original post.